# Passing an image from JavaScript to C# in an ASP.NET app?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an Image variable loaded in a `JavaScript` app, and I want to pass it to a `C#` method in my `ASP.NET` app (so I can store it in a database).  The only problem I am having is getting the image's data itself to the `C#` method.  I tried using an `AJAX` call (it's a `GET`) with the `C#`'s method's `byte[]` parameter set to the Image's .Picture, but the `byte[]` is empty.

How do I get the image's data from the JavaScript script to the C# method?

**UPDATE:**
I tried copying the image to a canvas using drawImage on the canvas's rendering context, but the image has to come from my local computer, so when I subsequently try to call canvas.toDataURL, it throws a DOM Security error.

I also considered using FileReader to get the data directly rather than loading it as an image, but, for political reasons, I have to support browsers that don't implement FileReader yet.

Am I asking for something that just isn't possible in JavaScript?  (There must be a way of doing this (not necessarily in JS), as Facebook implements loading images from the client computer's local file system.)

Comment: did you make sure your names match?  The property on the model must match the property you send.  If it's a property in an object, like SomeThing.SomeProperty then you need to have a SomeThing object on your model for the binding to push SomeProperty into it.  If your model has SomeProperty but you send SomeThing.SomeProperty then SomeProperty will be null.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you load your image in `javascript` app. But when i faced the same issue , i did it in the follwing way.

**HTML**

```
  <input id="imgInput" type="file"  name="file" />
  <img id="imagePreview" src="" alt="Item Image" width="96" height="80"/>
  <input id="Button1" type="button" value="save image"  onclick="saveimage();"/>
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#imgInput").change(function () {

                readURL(this);

            });

        });
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {

                    $('#imagePreview').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }

        function saveimage() {
            var images = $('#imagePreview').attr('src');
            var ImageSave = images.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
            var submitval = JSON.stringify({ data: ImageSave });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                data: submitval,
                url: "your url",
                success: function (data) {
                     //code for success
                }
            });
        }
```

**.CS**

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string saveimage(string data) {
        byte[] imgarr = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
         /* Add further code here*/
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for political reasons, I am stuck with browsers that do not support FileReader() yet